# "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."

Tags: discussion, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ajax.googleapis.com blocked by OpenDNS. Confirmation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117839/ajax-googleapis-com-blocked-by-opendns-confirmation)

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but since this morning when I opened StackOverflow that error appears on the top of the page.

I'm on FF and I'm not using any popup/code blocker. I've tried also with Google Chrome but the errors remains.

Anyone else with the same error? How to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a temporary outage (for you) of google's CDN. Check that you can download http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js . In particular, [OpenDNS is known to block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117839/ajax-googleapis-com-blocked-by-opendns-confirmation) the google CDN.

It is also possible that a local proxy or other software is rewriting the page. Do allow us to determine whether that's the case, copy the source code (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) of the root HTML page, upload it to http://pastebin.com, and post a link to it.

Comment: It returned to normal by itself :) Thanks

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: Yes OpenDNS seems to have problems with ajax.googleapis.com. I cleared DNS cache (ipconfig /flushdns) and re-registered dns (ipconfig /registerdns) and this removed the problem, only temporarily. It came back later and forced me to remove OpenDNS entries from DNS list.