# Cannot log-in to StackOverflow. 404 Not Found from global

Tags: bug, login

Browser: Firefox 28.

I'm getting a "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load." error.

[image]

From the StackOverflow site itself:

[image]

From the StackOverflow log-in page:

[image]

I am currently logged-in to StackOverflow via Chromium, and I dare not log-out lest I lose access. This is probably a network issue (eg. filtering in a corporate network), but can anybody confirm if that may be the case?

**UPDATE #1 Mar 21 16:54H:** It's using HTTPS for the libraries: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js, and I can't open it. But if I change it to http, it works. Not sure if this is a network issue, or if Google has disabled https access. I have no access to a machine outside the corporate network.

Answer (score -1):

> It seems that I had to clear the cache and refresh the page once for each domain.

See lot of discussions there

["Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message)

["Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117851/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-which-is-block)

Comment: Clearing the cache was a bad idea. Now, I'm signed out from all StackExchange sites in Firefox. Fortunately, I still have my accounts signed-in via Chromium. Must be a network thing; I can access the the jquery library. It's the StackExchange library that's failing for me. Any idea where this is hosted?